# Getting WebView content, or cookies

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the current content of a WebView?

What about Cookies for a specific host+url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the current
>   content of a WebView?

No, sorry.

> What about Cookies for a specific
>   host+url?

See [`CookieManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get the current
>   content of a WebView?

Not view the WebView object, but you could get the url via [WebViewClient.onLoadResource](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) and get the content by using sockets.

Comment: First, that will retrieve the data twice, meaning twice the cost in terms of CPU, bandwidth, and battery life. Second, unless you are very careful about your HTTP headers, you might not get the same thing -- the server might serve different content for `WebView` than for an `HttpClient` object, for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare Third, WebView does Javascript rendering for you, HttpClient doesn't. See unanswered question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200318/html-javascript-renderer-that-outputs-html-or-plaintext