# HTML + Javascript Renderer that outputs HTML or plaintext?

Tags: java, javascript, android, html

If I use:

```
String plain = Html.fromHtml(html).toString;
```

to render simple 'html' that contains:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Google</title>
  </head>
  <body>any plain vanila HTML goes here
  </body>
```

All is nice and dandy.

But what if that page contains tons of Javascript code that is nicely rendered by all web browsers but isn't available to me?

Is there a renderer that takes care of the Javascript as well, to output HTML or plaintext, that **isn't necessarily going to a visual display**?

(I know about [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) but my understanding that I can't really access its output. Or can I?)

Comment: And what if that tons of JS means the page could pull up any one of 10,000+ different videos or documentation files (or whatever)?  Would you expect the output to include static HTML variants for all 10,000+ pages?

Comment: @Andrew Go to http://youtu.be/FuXEXBg2giI, select all (Ctrl+A), Copy (Ctrl+C), then paste it to an HTML editor (e.g. Komposer). Did you receive HTML variants for *all* possible outputs of the tons of Javascript code that you see when you view the page source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a renderer that takes care of the Javascript as well, to output HTML or plaintext, that isn't necessarily going to a visual display?

`WebView` or bust.

> (I know about WebView but my understanding that I can't really access its output. Or can I?)

1. Create a Java object to receive your output
2. Add that Java object to the `WebView` via `addJavascriptInterface()`
3. Use `loadUrl("javascript:...")` on the `WebView` to invoke a hunk of Javascript that gathers your information and calls a method on your Java object

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you so much. Do you happen to know of a sample or an example that demonstrates what you described?

Comment: @Regex Rookie: Well, this sample shows the Android portions of it: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/WebView/GeoWeb2  However, figuring out the "hunk of Javascript that gathers your information" is up to you.

Comment: Note to self: In this sample, **Locater** is the Java object serving as the Javascript interface. Also note the use of a JSON object.

Comment: @Regex Rookie: The JSON object is for atomicity of the data. I had an earlier version of `Locater` that had `getLatitude()` and `getLongitude()` methods. An astute reader of the book pointed out that a GPS fix might arrive between those two calls, resulting in an invalid latitude/longitude pair. The JSON structure allows `Locater` to return both latitude and longitude at one time.

Comment: @CommonsWare What do you mean by "hunk of Javascript that gathers your information"?

Comment: @Regex Rookie: Here's a fully-worked-out solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-web-view/4892013#4892013